# super() class inheritance, Diamond Problem

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass

Why when I call `super()` in the class `WordCounter` it calls the class `Vocabulary` even though it's not inheriting from? Shouldn't it call class `Tokenizer` instead?

```
class Tokenizer:
    """Tokenize text"""
    def __init__(self, text):
        print('Start Tokenizer.__init__()')
        print('End Tokenizer.__init__()')


class Vocabulary(Tokenizer):
    """Find unique words in text"""
    def __init__(self, text):
        print('Start init Vocabulary.__init__()')
        print('End init Vocabulary.__init__()')


class WordCounter(Tokenizer):
    """Count words in text"""
    def __init__(self, text):
        print('Start WordCounter.__init__()')
        super().__init__(text)
        print('End WordCounter.__init__()')


class TextDescriber(WordCounter, Vocabulary):
    """Describe text with multiple metrics"""
    def __init__(self, text):
        print('Start init TextDescriber.__init__()')
        super().__init__(text)
        print('End init TextDescriber.__init__()')


td = TextDescriber('row row row your boat')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Start init TextDescriber.__init__()
Start WordCounter.__init__()
Start init Vocabulary.__init__()
End init Vocabulary.__init__()
End WordCounter.__init__()
End init TextDescriber.__init__()
```

Answer (score 3):

Diamond inheritance is always a bit of a mess. Every language has its own quirks, and Python is no exception. (Note that I'm explaining "new style" classes in Python. There are also "classic" classes in Python 2, which behave differently)

What Python does for all inheritance, is to render an order in which to check parent classes if the current class does not implement the requested method/property. You can inspect this Method Resolution Order dynamically. Your example yields

```py
>>> print(TextDescriber.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.TextDescriber'>, <class '__main__.WordCounter'>, <class '__main__.Vocabulary'>, <class '__main__.Tokenizer'>, <class 'object'>)
```

As you can see, Python chose to go left-to-right, and only afterwards descend in the hierarchy ([full details](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)).

What `super()` does is call the next method in this `__mro__`. This chain stops at `Vocabulary.__init__()`, since this method has no `super().__init__()` call for the chain to continue.

If you include a `super().__init__()` call in `Vocabulary.__init__()`, this will work as expected:

```
Start init TextDescriber.__init__()
Start WordCounter.__init__()
Start init Vocabulary.__init__()
Start Tokenizer.__init__()
End Tokenizer.__init__()
End init Vocabulary.__init__()
End WordCounter.__init__()
End init TextDescriber.__init__()
```

Comment: Thank you @Niobos for explaining the MRO but that doesn't tell me why it's choosing Vocabulary instead of Tokenizer? Like what is the logic behind it?

Comment: This is just how Python defines the inheritance order. I've added a link to the full spec if you want to learn more about all the edge-cases.

Comment: @Kashan. Remember that the call to `super().__init__(text)` in `WordCounter.__init__` equivalent to `super(WordCounter, self).__init__(text)`. The two arguments mean "use the mro of `self`, starting with `WordCounter`". We're used to seeing `self` being of type `WordCounter` or having single inheritance from it. When that's not the case, the parent of `WordCounter` may not be the next thing in the mro, as you see here. That's what the sentence "What `super()` does is call the next method in this `__mro__`" in the answer means.